# javascript/jquery won't load until after python cgi script has

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cgi

I have a python cgi script that prints out some javascript/jquery in `<head>`. I want the javascript to load before the slow python calculations occur further down in the python script, and in the body. I have two simple hello world alerts that show the issue. The first one prints out before the python calculations, which is what I want. However, the second one, located in `$(function(){...})`, does not load until after the python calculations. The actual code I have contains (more than a hello world alert) a simple jquery drop down toolbar. How can I get the jquery to load before the rest of the python cgi script?

```
print('<head>')
<...jquery source...>
print('''
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert( "Hello World! 1" );           <-------This prints out before python below 
    $(function(){
           alert( "Hello World! 2" );    <-------This prints out after python below
    });
    </script>
''')
print('</head>')

**<...lots of slow python calculations...>**
```

Comment: You can't; it doesn't really make any sense. Either take that code inside the jQuery "ready" handler out of there, so that it's like your first alert, or else speed up the Python code. The whole point of a "ready" handler is to wait for the entire document to be read by the browser.

Comment: You could also split the page into two pieces, so that you load a framework/skeleton page first, and then fetch the slow stuff with ajax.

Comment: You can't because the document won't be ready until *<insert server language>* has completely returned all of the document.

Comment: Why does the alert being inside $(function()) make a difference? It's still javascript.

Comment: Because `$(function() {})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function () {...})`.

Comment: How do I take it out and still use jquery and refer to specific namespaces?